# C++ multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, c, syntax, multidimensional-array, operators

We have the code:

```
int arr[3][4];
```

So `arr` is:

1. An array of 3 elements, and every element is an array of 4 int.
2. An array of 4 elements, and every element is an array of 3 int.

which one is right and why? How does it work with higher dimensional array? I suppose this is concerning operator precedence and associativity.

Comment: Perhaps what you are asking is about [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) vs column-major order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first interpretation is correct.

Such declarations are best parsed using the **Right Left rule**, which you can read [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31783&seqNum=7) and [here](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html)

$8.3.4 from the C++ draft Standard:
...

> Example: consider int x[3][5]; Here x is a 3 × 5 array of integers.

...

> Note: It follows from all this that arrays in C++ are stored **row-wise**
>   (last subscript varies fastest) and that the first subscript in the
>   declaration helps determine the amount of storage consumed by an array
>   but plays no other part in subscript calculations. —end note ]

Note C++ does not have operator[][]. It has only operator[]

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to think of the "rows" and "columns" in a multidimensional array rather than trying to get my mind around "arrays of arrays". This has the convenient property that *I* decide which index is the rows and which is the columns. In other words, I can think of `int arr[3][4];` as a 2D array either with 3 rows and 4 columns or with 4 rows and 3 columns. As long as my code is consistent with my mental view of the array, all will work out fine. However, if half-way through a program I switch views, things will start breaking.

With that said, usually I prefer to think of this example as 3 rows and 4 columns since this is similar to the mathematical notation in linear algebra where rows are listed first.

Comment: It is important to stick to row-major access behavior if you want to get good cache performance.

Comment: @Pubby Good point! I think that is information beyond the scope of this particular question and certainly would belong in a more in-depth discussion of C++ arrays.